# Jpa select with relations

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have 4 tables in relations. A,B,C,D.

So I wrote select bellow:

```
select NEW org.example.ExtendsA(a,b.name,c.name,d.name)
from A a LEFT JOIN a.bItems b LEFT JOIN a.cItems c LEFT JOIN b.dItems d 
order by b.name ASC;
```

A is unique but the relations are incomplette.

and I tried this:

```
select NEW org.example.ExtendsA(a,b.name,c.name,d.name)
from A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bItems b LEFT JOIN FETCH  a.cItems c
LEFT JOIN FETCH b.dItems d order by b.name ASC;
```

A is not unique.

A object definition is:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aId")
    private List<B> bItems;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aId")
    private List<C> cItems;

}
```

Some relations are empty but need A object with null relations. 
Some A object has more than one relations between B and C and I want to select with all in one A object (distinct A).

Would you help me how to solve this issue? Maybe the approach is bad?

I use EclipeLink data provider.

Comment: what do you mean by unique? it is a table

Comment: My goal is: The object A appears only once in the select and contains the relations. The unique word in this environment may not be a good choice.

Comment: For example: distinct (A)

Comment: Show A object definition.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem with loading `OneToMany` relathionships.

This is because of the nature of SQL result sets. Imagine a SQL result of a join of entity with it's other entities linked to it. On the left side, fields of this entity will be duplicated as many times as many related entities it has.

Unforunately, EclipseLink doesn't filter them out and you get many items of the same entity in your result. Although, EclipseLink is smart enough and each item will actually be the same Java object instance.

It's also the reason why you can't use `setMaxResults` in such queries.

You need to use `distinct` keyword that in this particular keys will not be mapped to a real SQL distinct, but will filter duplicated entities. Or, you can filter them manually.